# How can I send keys combination to Android emulator using c# and Appium?

Tags: c#, android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I want to change device emulator orientation by sending LeftCtrl + F12.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To change screen orientation use appium rotate API :
`driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT);
driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: It looks like an example for Java. Could you provide an example for C#?